# Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a problem when i start my first spring application with spring tools suite,
This is the error,Located in POM.XML:

`Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM`

Comment: Having issues firewall/proxy etc. other warnings in your build?

Comment: Try `clean install -U`

Comment: Hi i resolve the probleme of proxy,but now i see this problem in POM.XML :
"org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)"